# In TeamCity how can I use an xcode build step on a project that is created in an earlier step?

Tags: xcode, build, teamcity

I have a build system that takes an Expo React-Native project and 'ejects' the underlying iPhone app build project (the xcodeproj and workspace etc)

however as these files don't exist at the time I am creating the build steps the wizard that wants to help me find the scheme cannot find the file and so cannot set itself up.

What is my work around here? Do I have to devolve back to a command line only system (I am not sure how to do that!) or can I trick TeamCity in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for this yet... but it is clear that the command line is king here and my complete solution will involve https://docs.fastlane.tools/ in some way.